# ReactJS setState only once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to set navbar background colour depending on Y scroll position of a webpage. The problem is once I get in between Y coordinates where I want to setState of my navbar background it won't stop setting it until the page freezes. Here is my code for better understanding:

Getting the Y scroll position, checking if its between 600 & 650, if true setting navbar background colour:

```
const [navbarBg, setNavbarBg] = useState(style_buttons)

function runOnScroll() {
  const scrolled = window.scrollY
  if (scrolled > 600 && scrolled < 650) {
    setNavbarBg(style_project1)
  }
}

window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll)
```

It keeps setting the state even when I'm not scrolling and I don't know how to break out of it.

I tried using UseEffect but I don't think I clearly understand how to use it.

Can anyone please help?

Thank you

Comment: Is `window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll)` called in the main render function?

Comment: What is considered to be a render function if I'm using only functional components? I am calling it in the function above the return() statement in App.js

Comment: The render function is anything that goes directly into the body of the function component that is not part of some sort of callback mechanism like `useEffect`. From what you say it sounds like you've placed it there. You say you've tried to use `useEffect`, which would be the correct way to go. Could you add your attempt and what the problem with it is?

Comment: I think you are right with what I did wrong. The problem is I don't really know what part of my code should be in useEffect. Should I set my state there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned in the comments that the `window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll)` event listener is before the return function so there would be multiple listener configured as React will run the function body on each re-render.

You need to add the event listener in the `useEffect` hook and remove/cleanup the listener on component unmount.

In the given code the event listener executes on each render and hence there would be multiple listener getting configured.

**Solution:**

You could add the listener in `useEffect` hook and remove the listener in the `useEffect` callback and pass an empty array as the dependency (to run the hook only once), with this approach there will be only one listener.

```
const someComponent = function () {

    const [navbarBg, setNavbarBg] = useState(style_buttons)
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll)
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);
        }
    },[]);
    function runOnScroll() {
        const scrolled = window.scrollY
        if (scrolled > 600 && scrolled < 650) {
            setNavbarBg(style_project1)
        }
    }
    return (
        <>
        </>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current problem is that you add a new scroll event listener every time the component is rendered. So after the first render you've got 1 event listener, after the second render 2, 3 after the third render etc. This is basically a memory leak because they are never removed.

By using `useState` you can control how often the event handler is added, but more importantly you can return a cleanup function from `useEffect`. See the [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) documentation for more details.

All references to variables that are not defined within the callback itself should be added to the dependency list (second array argument of `useState`). Unless it is guaranteed that the identity of these variables is stable (the object/value stays the same).

```
const [navbarBg, setNavbarBg] = useState(style_buttons)

useState(() => {
  function runOnScroll() {
    const scrolled = window.scrollY;
    if (scrolled > 600 && scrolled < 650) {
      setNavbarBg(style_project1);
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);
  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", runOnScroll);
}, [style_project1]);
```

Since we know `window` and `setNavbarBg` (see [`useState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)) never change they can be left out of the dependency list. However, since you don't provide any info about `style_project1` I've added it, just to be sure. If you know this will always hold the same object/value you can change the dependency list to `[]`.

If you don't specify a dependency list things still work, but the callback will be executed after every render. Meaning that each time the component is rendered, the previous scroll event is removed and a new one is added. By adding a dependency list it will only re-run (and cleanup beforehand) when the values in the list change. Which should be a lot more infrequent resulting in better performance.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The answer above solved my problem but I will definitely have a look at this solution too to get better understanding of React Hooks.